# How to initialise enumerator array using ints instead of Enumerator.value

Tags: java, enums

I have enumerator

```
public enum Tile{
    Empty(0),
    Occupied(1);
}
```

I want to create 2D array using **ints** instead of Tile.Empty or Tile.Occuppied

```
var shape = new Tile[][]{
            {0, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 1}, 
     };
```

Is it possible to do it in JAVA?

Comment: Not with `var`, but you can simply use `int[][]` as reference. So: `int[][] shape = {{1,2},{3,4}};`.

Comment: If you need to somehow reference `Tile` instead of using literal values, you'll need a getter in your `enum` that returns the field (e.g. `getNumber`), and to reference it as `Tile.Empty.getNumber()` etc.

Comment: The thing is I want to have Tile Array instead of int Array, but the problem lies in initialisation. Instead of writing {Tile.Empty, Tile.Empty, Tile.Occupied} I want to write {0, 0, 1}. Or should I just stick with the former option?

Comment: if your array should be of type `Tile`, then you can't really populate it with `int`s. What you could *also* do is to add a static method to your enum, something in the lines of `forValue(int i)` that returns the relevant `Tile` if found, and does *something* otherwise. Then you can use `Tile.forValue(0)` etc. while populating your array values.

Comment: Thank you :) Also I cannot find a way to mark this question as answered.

Comment: That's because there is technically no answer - we sorted it in the comments :D I'll come up with something, give me a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize an `int` array with the keyword `var`.

However, you can reference it with a strong type reference, e.g.: `int[][] shape = {{1,2},{3,4}};`.

You also cannot populate an array of type `Tile` with elements that are not `Tile`, e.g. `int`s.

What you can do is either initialize:

- an array of `int` literals
- an array of `Tile` literals
- an array of `int`s whose literal values are retrieved from the desired `Tile` elements through a getter in the `Tile` class definition, or
- an array of `Tile`s whose instances are constructed from an `int` literal - for that you could implement a static method in the `Tile` class that takes an `int` parameter and returns the corresponding `Tile` or complains if not found (throw some exception for instance)